# Trouble evaluating a formula in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting this program to evaluate a range of values through a formula.

> range = (-3.0,4.0) formula = (9(x^3)-27(x^2)-4x+12) / (sqrt(3(x^2)+1)
>   + abs(5-(x^4)))

The program prints out the `y as -1.IND`

Any help on shedding light on why all the y comes out as `-1.IND` is appreciated.

Thanks, Dave

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "This program outputs formula results\n";
    long double x = -3.0;
    long double y = 1.0;
    long double a = (9*(pow(x,3))-27*(pow(x,2))-4*x+12);
    long double b = (sqrt(3*(pow(x,2))+1) + abs(5-(pow(x,4))));
    y = a/b;

        for(;x <4.5; x=x+.5){
            cout << "X = " << x << ", " << "Y = " << y;
        if(y==0)
            cout << "Y IS ZERO" << endl;
        else if(y<0)
            cout << "Y IS NEGATIVE" << endl;
        else if(y>0)
            cout << "Y IS POSITIVE\n" << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance, try the word "problems" before settling on "trouble"?

Comment: `3*(pow(x,3))` is not the same as `3(x^2)`. Typo?

Comment: You are never changing `y`. C++ is an imperative language, you need to re-calculate the value, otherwise it won’t change.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel We love drama!

Comment: What you need to do, is to examine the value of each variable. Find where the actual results begin to diverge from your expected results. Then, since you'll have maybe four or five characters to work with, you'll probably see the trouble. This is something that you should do on your own.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `y = a/b;` isn't a "change"?

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Okay, “You never change `y` inside the loop”

Comment: @thang Go outside, have an ice cream. Don’t take your angst out on beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `x` is `-3`, or negative in general, you're trying to calculate `sqrt(3*(pow(x,3))` which is a square root of a negative number. That's why you're getting weird results. Using `pow` is not terribly efficient for calculating integer powers. But for small programs it may not matter.

Addendum: As Nawaz notes in the comment, please do reevaluate y every time in the loop or else you will only get y for the initial x.

Comment: He also seems to think that in each iteration value of `y` will be printed different, because `x` is changing :P

Comment: I'm afraid he might *only* do `y = a/b` inside the loop, not `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's his problem, methinks :)

Comment: thanks everybody, I am going to look over these suggestions and make the changes.

Comment: I can't find a `pow(x,3)` inside a `sqrt` call anywhere.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: The question was edited

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: That explains it then

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate `y` in the loop, not just once.

As @simonc commented -- The entire equation needs to be recalculated for each `x`

Comment: You also need to calculate `a` and `b`

Comment: @simonc: Certainly. The entire equation needs to be recalculated for each `x`

Comment: Yep.  It'd be clearer if you said this in your answer.  It could currently be mis-interpreted as meaning that *only* `y` needs to be recalculated.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for the detailed explanations, I made the changes and the results came out as expected. To show that the changes worked, the result of X=-2.5, Y=-7.46301

Answer (score 0):

You are computing your formula only for x = -3 and for that value you are trying to get the square root of a negative number. Move the computation of y inside the loop.